# How to zip files into multiple files (not splitted and not indivisually)

Tags: linux, zip

I have around 200k `*.html` file that I need to zip, each around 100mb (can be less or more a bit no problem) but **not** split to parts like this `**zip.001 **zip.002` so I can unzip one of the files without issues **which is the most important**

What command can help to do this?

Comment: are they just plain text .html files?

Comment: yes all .html no other 200k file and total size 26GB

Comment: Why not just put them in a folder and use the `zip` command on the folder?

Comment: have you tried compressing the whole thing, or even a portion, to see how small it becomes?  Pure text will compress very well.